# Объявление типа ArrayList

Tags: java, list

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста в чем разница объявления типа для `ArrayList`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
```

и

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
```

?

Comment: Это называется полиморфизм. Работа с объектом через его интерфейс, основа основ ООП

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В первом случае переменной лист можно присвоить любой объект, класс которого имплементирует интерфейс List.

Во втором случае - это должен быть ArrayList или его наследники.

Answer (score 2):

List - это интерфейс, то есть объявление методов, а ArrayList это уже конкретная реализация данного интерфейса. Если меня не подводит память, уже несколько лет с Java не работал.

Comment: Ну то что ArrayList имплементирует List это понятно,но в чем тогда разница объявления типа List или ArrayList если функционал один и тот же?

Comment: В данном случает нет никакой разницы между List и ArrayList. Так как, в обоих случаях создаётся объект ArrayList.

Comment: ну, например, при объявлении List вам не будут доступны методы  ensureCapacity() и  trimToSize(). Точнее, вам нужно будет явно кастовать объект к ArrayList. Если этим методы вам не нужны, то объявляйте список как List. Принято определять минимально необходимый интерфейс, как можно выше по иерархии наследования. ArrayList реализует List, т.е. List выше. Если вам нужна просто коллекция, то лучше определить как Collection

Comment: Спасибо,вот тут уже понятнее!