# Почему так не рекомендуется писать?

Tags: java, android, задание-на-собеседовании

Делал тестовое задание на вакансию Junior Android разработчика, в коде была строчка:

```
ArrayList<String> valNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Мне сказали, что лучше писать так:

```
List<String> valNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Потом в одной из статей на habrahabr.ru встретилась фраза:

> Подумаешь, большое дело, что человек не понимает почему нужно писать 
>   List values = new ArrayList(); вместо ArrayList values = ….; Ну и кому
>   же не хочется увидеть названия в стиле ArrayList arrayList = new
>   ArrayList(); и улыбнуться. Жаль только, что с применением данного
>   антипатерна, все эти, вызывающие улыбку, вещи обычно обнаруживаются
>   после приблизительно месяца работы.

Объясните, почему так писать неправильно. Формально - ошибки нет?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600330/191482   ........... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429978/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-arraylist/429980#comment442376_429980

Comment: Благодарю, теперь понятно!

Comment: На деле, ошибки нету, это вопрос того, как принято в данном языке.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно это объясняется так: если кодер объявляет переменную типа `ArrayList<String>` вместо `List<String>` - он не понимает что все нужные ему методы уже есть в интерфейсе. Тем самым демонстрируется непонимание основных принципов проектирования, ведь ему на самом деле совсем не требуется именно `ArrayList<String>`, он может использовать любую другую коллекцию! ... с той же асимптотикой операций... упс.

На самом деле те, кто так пишет, *<s>защищаются от автоматических рефакторингов, способных преобразовать переменную конкретного типа в параметр метода, что проявит их непонимание основных принципов проектирования</s>* привыкли к IDE, которые подчеркивают такие места желтым и предлагают исправить тип переменной. Это просто привычка.

Для большинства алгоритмов, выдумываемых на ходу, `ArrayList<>` является единственной коллекцией с адекватными временами выполнения операций и нет никакой разницы какого типа объявлять переменную.

А вот за типами параметров методов или возвращаемых значений надо и правда следить внимательнее, выбирая наименьший подходящий интерфейс - это упростит стыковку кода, написанного разными программистами.

Comment: Спасибо, с этой стороны не смотрел. Привык "прибивать гвоздями" - если нужен ArrayList, значит это будет именно ArrayList. На курсах на этих моментах не акцентировались.

Answer (score 0):

Это носит больше религиозно/стилистический оттенок, нежели формальный.

Объявление `List<String>` шире чем декларация `ArrayList<String>`, то есть когда человек пишет `List<String>` он типа демонстрирует свою ООП сущность, как бы понимает, что *underlying* объект может быть и `ArrayList` и `Vector` и `Stack` и т.д. и декларируя `List` абстрагируется от конкретной реализации.

На самом то деле, насколько это правильно или нет - напоминает дискуссии средневековых схоластов [о сущности универсалий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Жесткость оценок, это тоже из раздела схоластики, как известно победители в схоластических спорах заживо сжигали своих оппонентов - так все нормально :)

Comment: Спасибо, я понял!